# Mission Control not working

Tags: macos, mission-control

Mission Control isn't working on my Mac. I've tried killing the Dock through Terminal and Activity Monitor multiple times, but nothing seems to be working. Even shortcuts or Hot Corners don't work anymore.

What do I do?

Comment: Have you rebooted your Mac?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the Finder?

Answer (score 2):

This was happening to me for a long time and I did some research and found out how to fix it. 
Go into terminal and run the following commands.

```
defaults write com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled -bool FALSE
killall Dock
```

This should fix all of your problems.